# How do I convert DateTime to yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00.000Z format in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert dateTime to the above given format. I tried to look the docs but didnt find much information.

Comment: You should paste some code of what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just pass the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'"` to `ToString`

```
string str = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'");
```

Comment: Dammit Habib!  You beat me to it again :P

Comment: `Datetime.Now.ToString("O")` is the same.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, it would return `2013-10-28T15:05:57.0787202-04:00`

Comment: @Habib yes, that is correct if the current DateTime contains a timezone adjustment. If you don't want the timezone then use `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O")`. Both are equal to the same time and both are valid ISO-8601 timestamps.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, yes, also `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O")`

Comment: This has a typo it should be ```string format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z'"```

Answer (score 0):

If your DateTime Object is Nullable then use this

```
string str = DateTime.Now.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'");
```

Answer (score -1):

`ToString` won't work. Try the below code, it works:

```
String formatted = Datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
```